# Auto-create implementation in Visual Studio C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was wondering if there was a way to write a complete header file and have Visual Studio create an appropriate implementation file to save all of that extra work. I feel like they must have thought of it as it's such a simple thing but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: [Asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610011/creating-cpp-files-from-h-files-visual-studio) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055350/any-way-to-build-cpp-skeleton-from-a-header) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020568/seeking-code-stub-generator-from-header-files) I'd say.

Comment: Real men write the implementation by hand. In binary. Directly on disk, with a magnetic needle and a steady hand.
:P

Comment: A real men woudn't need computers to do things... invalidating the previous theory... we are all LAZY MEN at the end! =)

Comment: @Bart But none of these are relevant to visual studio **2010**

Comment: @user1031643 When you read through the posts you will see that Visual Assist has been suggested several times. As have various other tools/scripts. You can use these. I don't know of a truly internal solution for VS.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeWiz](http://www.cupla.net/CodeWiz2/) is a **free** Visual Studio addin containing lots of features. I have used it a lot on Visual 2005. The best productivity boost for me came from the fast implement method key sequence :

1. On the .h file select methods you want to implement
2. CTRL-5 (CodeWiz2.CopyMembers)
3. CTRL-1 (CodeWiz2.FriendFile : navigate between .h and .cpp so here go to .cpp)
4. CTRL-6 (CodeWiz2.PasteMembers) : Will implements methods as empty

Far from ideal but I miss it on visual studio 2012...