# Is there an automated shortcut in VC++ to make the typed header signature into a body in the .cpp file?

Tags: visual-studio

In VC++ 2017, is there a quick way of typing the member function declaration in the header file, and then it automatically builds the required body for you in the .cpp file?

For example, typing

```
void show();
```

in Vector2.h, can create the body

```
void show() { };
```

in the Vector2.cpp file with some keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way to generate code functions from header functions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961648/fast-way-to-generate-code-functions-from-header-functions-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `void show();` in the header, if there isn't already an implementation you should see a green underline under the declaration. Put your cursor on that line and press ctrl + . to open up the list of suggested actions, and then enter to choose the first, which should create the empty implementation as desired.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!